# Isolation in SDN planes

Tags: sdn

How exactly is  isolation between data and control planes in sdn designed e.g when we assume that SDN is in a server?. And what about isolation in SDN switches between data and control ports?

Answer (score 0):

SDN is a networking paradigm. A networking style. Before understanding SDN, we have to understand 2 things.
1.Data Plane: Data Path which actually forwards the packet or data from the input port to output port.
2.Control Plane: This has the logic of how to move the packet from input port to output port. Control Plane directs the data plane.

Pre SDN , the two planes data plane and control plane both were residing in the network devices like routers, switches, firewalls etc.
Now with SDN, the control plane and data plane has been separated i.e, Control Plane is moved out of the network devices and has been placed onto the central server. One SDN Controller can control many Network Elements. Granularity of the separation is left to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify SDN first imagine how traditional forwarding works

PC1 --- Router1 ----Router2-----Router3----PC2

For PC1 to reach PC2 it has to traverse through Router1, Router2 and Router3. Router 1 has information about its neighbors i.e router2. The same follows for other routers until it reaches PC2. If we observe the decision where to forward the packets is being taken by the routers at each step. The "Brain" is in the router which also acts as a device carrying the packets. This is analogous to our legs having its own brain to walk to a certain place.

In case of SDN the brain from each router is pulled up and put in one place. That is the controller or the control plane. Now the routers are just data/packets forwarding devices and hence are called switches in SDN. This is similar to how our brain works now. The brain decides how our legs and hands should move for us to reach a decision.

In SDN switch the switch talks to the control plane on virtual ports 6633 or 6653.

Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Software Defined Network is a concept. When you say "when we assume that SDN is on a server?", I will say it's not a thing that you can just put somewhere, it's a concept. This concept is based on some explicit points. A good implementation of SDN will ensure the points below.

1. Control plane - data plane separation
2. Centralized point of control
3. Miscellaneous: network programmability, scalability etc.

When you try to look for isolation in the SDN concept, what you are basically looking for is point 1. Let me explain it a bit if that helps.

The major reason we started SDN was to bring in more robust and better programmability in the network. And one thing that was stopping us to do so is the distributed nature of network deployments. Bringing any change in network properties or behaviour required to explicitly go in and run some configurations in many router/switches in a deployment. That introduces all sorts of complexity and errors proneness.

For example, suppose we want packets from particular ip or ip mask to go through a special service function (e.g. firewall) which will decide the fate of the packet. Now, we will have to put this configuration into all the border routers or a group of devices that might receive the packet. In a big deployment, it can be a countless number of devices where we have to put this configuration to securely ensure the enforcement of the policy.

So, the idea of decoupling the network control from the data forwarding devices came along. This effectively means that we will have a *dumb* data forwarding service which can be controlled by a network controller or programmer. The data plane, which provides this data packet forwarding service, remains at router and switch level whereas the control plane might be and should be a separate physical entity. Conceptually, they are separated but it's not isolated.

One core benefit of SDN is that it enables the network control logic to be designed and operated on a global network view, as though it were a centralized application. Network control plane is thought to be a logically centralized application where we make the changes which will enforce our intended behaviour in the network.

In summary, what we basically do in SDN is, we take all those control-level business logic away from forwarding devices (means, physical and virtual switches and routers), and put them together in an application which we call controller and then we provide a way for the controller application to communicate and program changes in data plane forwarding devices. A good study to completely understand this architecture will be this: [Understanding OpenFlow](https://sdngeeks.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/understanding-openflow.pdf).

Long story short, *isolation* is a slightly wrong word to put between data plane and control plane. It's more like they were *separated* but dependent on each other. Without a control plane, forwarding devices are dumb, without the data plane, the control plane has nothing to control!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, its not the implementation location that defines the separation(isolation), rather its because of the standard between control and data-plane (openflow for instance).
You can have both data and control planes on single server and they are separated as long as they talk through the standard interface. 
The opposite case is also true, you can have control and data-plane physically separated, but if they are not through and standard interface, thats not SDN per se.

just go through ONF explanations:
https://www.opennetworking.org/software-defined-standards/overview/